# App Center not showing crashes for Xcode/TestFlight distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, testflight, visual-studio-app-center

For an iOS beta project in a Xamarin Forms app with App Center, I injected test crash code (division by zero). When I load the app locally over USB and invoke the crash, a crash report appears in App Center diagnostics showing the call stack. The method names are symbolicated (not sure how, since I had not uploaded symbols yet) but without line numbers. Uploading zipped symbols from the same build afterwards made no difference. (Analytics came through Ok.)

However when I distribute the exact same app via Xcode/TestFlight (not Fastlane) and invoke the crash, no crash report appears in App Center diagnostics. (Analytics again come through OK.)

I did restart the app immediately after crashing each time.

So my question is, is it normal not to get App Center crash reports with Xcode/TestFlight? And given that I don't, could I nevertheless expect to get App Center crash reports after I submit to App Store production via Xcode? Or to get crash reports, am I expected to use the native App Center distribution, rather than Xcode? Or would Fastlane solve the problem? I'm unable to find any of this in documentation or web searches. Help appreciated! All software latest version.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things please - what's the XCode version, what's the iOS beta version, and is it possible to have a look at verbose logs? Usually those should still work (given that there is no debugger attached since that would prevent crashreporter from gathering crash information)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. Actually it is my app that is in beta, I'm using standard iOS 13.5.1, Xcode 11.6 and App Center 3.4.0. I found a solution (below), although maybe line numbers should be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the App Center instructions I had installed two Nugets, Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes and Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics. As these depend on Microsoft.AppCenter, the Microsoft.AppCenter NuGet should have been installed automatically. However it turns out it was not.

After I added the Microsoft.AppCenter NuGet and distributed the app through Xcode/TestFlight, things started working:

1. Crashes now appear in the App Center Diagnostics panel. Here is an example:

```
ModePage.InitialiseBehaviourAsync ()
ModePage.HandleStartSamplingClickedAsync ()
ModePage.OnStartSamplingButtonClicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply ()
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

On the upside, method names are symbolicated (even though I had not uploaded symbols to App Center). (I had uploaded symbols to Xcode.) On the downside, there are no line numbers. I don't know if there are supposed to be line numbers, would love to know.

On the Unsymbolicated tab, I see 'You're awesome! There are no unsymbolicated issues.'

2. When I now upload a matching zipped dSYM file to App Center, nothing is different.

Comment: The App Center documentation would benefit from a comment to check that the AppCenter NuGet has been installed.

Comment: Hm... I'll discuss the nuget part with team. As for symbolication - that's runtime symbolication from PLCR we are using in Apple SDK. And regarding line numbers - those should be present. To troubleshoot that I'd suggest to open support ticket on intercom (accessible via portal - topright corner, question mark > Contact Support), since there might be quite a few details to clarify.

Comment: Uh-oh. Seems like this issue has been around for a long time  :(   https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3657